# PHP array syntax error

Tags: php, arrays

I tried running this array but each time I get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\soap-service\AnchorSoapClient.php on line 75

Here is my PHP code:

```
public function submitorder(){
            $this->init(); 
            $result = $this->soapClient->SubmitOrder(array('SO'=>array('Flag_Rush_Order'=>'','Date_Ship_By'=>0,'Shipping_Charge'=>0), 'SO_Detail'=>array('SalesOrderDetail'=>
                array('Product_Seq_Id'=>0,'Order_Quantity'=>0,'Ship_Quantity'=>0,'Unit_Price'=>0,'Discount'=>0,'Extension'=>0,'Customer_ID'=>''),'Flag_All_Complete'=>'','Ship_method_Seq_Id'=>0,'Store_Name'=>'','Store_Message'=>'','Store_Street'=>'','Store_City'=>'','Store_State'=>'','Store_Zip'=>'','Store_Country'=>'','Intl_Tax_Number'=>'','Intl_Tax_Description'=>'Intl_Tax_Description','Intl_Tax_Amount'=>0,'Special_Instruction'=>'','Date_Shipped'=>'Date_Shipped'));  
            return $result;
        }
```

and this is the code in line 78:

```
$result = $this->soapClient->SubmitOrder(array('SO'=>array('Flag_Rush_Order'=>'','Date_Ship_By'=0,'Shipping_Charge'=>0), 'SO_Detail'=>
```

am not so good with PHP.

Comment: `'Date_Ship_By'=0,` should be `'Date_Ship_By'=>0,`

Comment: So many equals to(=) are given where there should be =>

Comment: ***Pro tip:*** Do not act needy and do not say your requirement is urgent. The folks answering questions are volunteers with busy lives, just like yours.

Comment: If you put all these arrays on 1 line you will lost the overview of what array values you have, put each new array on a new line it's a lot easier to debug when errors encountered.

Comment: @Debojyoti thats not true

Comment: Please just post here your problems if you face while using mkdir function.Not to know its syntax.

Comment: We get about 20 or 30 overly entitled people **every day** who ask for urgency and ASAP etc. It is draining and frustrating, and is an insult to volunteers who already give a lot of their time.

Answer (score 0):

Check `'Date_Ship_By'=0,`it should be `'Date_Ship_By'=>0,`
You have missed ")" at the end...

```
 $result = $this->soapClient->SubmitOrder(array('SO'=>array('Flag_Rush_Order'=>'','Date_Ship_By'=>0,'Shipping_Charge'=>0),
    'SO_Detail'=>array('SalesOrderDetail'=> array('Product_Seq_Id'=>0,'Order_Quantity'=>0,'Ship_Quantity'=>0,                    'Unit_Price'=>0,'Discount'=>0,'Extension'=>0,'Customer_ID'=>''),    'Flag_All_Complete'=>'','Ship_method_Seq_Id'=>0,'Store_Name'=>'','Store_Message'=>'',    'Store_Street'=>'','Store_City'=>'','Store_State'=>'','Store_Zip'=>'','Store_Country'=>'',    'Intl_Tax_Number'=>'','Intl_Tax_Description'=>'Intl_Tax_Description','Intl_Tax_Amount'=>0,'Special_Instruction'=>'','Date_Shipped'=>'Date_Shipped')));
```

Comment: okay, already fixed it came online saw that you guys actually gave the same solution. Thanks guys. Now the error is out, this time around am no longer getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\soap-service\AnchorSoapClient.php on line 75"

Comment: Here is the new error am getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\soap-service\AnchorSoapClient.php on line 75"

Comment: @C0dekid.php i have done that still cant trace the bug

Comment: please i still need your help guys